# javascript to set attribute readonly on dropdown value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

on selecting values from the drop down, if the selected  values equals to a certain value, i want the dropdown to change to readonly, how can i do that?

HTML:

```
<select id="s_id">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option></select>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#s_id").change(function () {
     var x = $(this).val();
     //alert("something's changed");
     alert($(this).val());
     if (x === opel) {
         alert("iff only.....");
         $(this).attr("readOnly", "true");
    }
   });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L4reds/xKQUd/2/

Comment: Firstly, you need to add quotes around the value condition: `if (x === "opel")...`. Secondly and more importantly, `select` elements cannot be made `readonly`. They can be `disabled`, but their value would then not be sent with the form data.

Comment: With "read only" you mean that value can't be selected?

Comment: Your line `if (x == opel) {`, variable `opel` is _undefined_. You probably wanted to compare against _String_; `if (x == 'opel') {`

Comment: also use `prop` instead of `attr`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to compare `x` to a string of `"opel"` and you can use the attribute `disabled`, see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xKQUd/3/

To clarify: `select` elements cannot be set to `readOnly`, need to use the `disabled` attribute

To get around the not sending to the server issue, set a hidden input equal to the disabled value that will be sent on form submission instead, view this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xKQUd/25/

Comment: There is the bigger issue however that a `select` element cannot be made `readonly`.

Comment: Hence why I said to use the disabled attribute

Comment: But that will mean that the value selected will never be sent to the server, which may be counter to what the OP requires. `disabled` is not a workable alternative.

Comment: just what i wanted....excellent answer. you seem to know it.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you used `opel` as a `variable`. but it's not a `variable` it's a `string`. So you need to take as a string (in single or double quotes).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#s_id").change(function () {
        var x = $(this).val();            
        alert($(this).val());
        alert("x=======" +x);
        if (x == "opel") {
            alert("iff");
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

[Try this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKQUd/19/)

or take a variable `var opel = "opel";`.

[Try jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKQUd/26/)

Answer (score 2):

`Select` elements can't be set `readonly`, but can be `disabled` instead. But in this case, their value won't be submitted with the `form`.

You have two options here.

One is to set a `hidden input` with the selected value, and then disable the `select`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#s_id").on("change", function () {
       if ($(this).val() === "opel") {
           $("#myHiddenField").val($(this).val());
           $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
       }
   });
});
```

The other one, is to remove all the other options from the `select`, leaving just the selected one available:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#s_id").on("change", function () {
     if ($(this).val() === "opel") {
         $(this).children("option").each(function() {
            if (this.value != "opel")
               this.remove();
         });
     }
   });
});
```

It's up to you now.

Answer (score 1):

`Select` doesn't have attr `ReadOnly` - instead it can be `disabled`
so your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#s_id").change(function () {
        var x = $(this).val();
        //alert("something's changed");
        alert($(this).val());
        alert("x=======" +x);
        if (x == "opel") {
            alert("iff");
           // $(this).attr("readOnly", "true");
            $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});
```

btw `open` is not a variable, but value, so needs to be in quotes `"opel"`
and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xKQUd/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code:

```
<select id="s_id">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#s_id").change(function () {
 var x = $(this).val();    
 if (x == 'opel') {
     $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
}
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ea6NN/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (x == 'opel') {
        alert("iff");
        $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
    }
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xKQUd/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (x == "opel") {

            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/xKQUd/24/

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
          y=1;
          $("#s_id").change(function () {
             var x = $(this).val();
    //alert("something's changed");


             if (x == "opel" && x!=y) {           
                y=x;
                $("#s_id").prop("disabled", true).change();            
    }
});
```

});